# Tablet RAM - how does it work?

Tags: operating-system, tablet, ram

Since Tablets have Flash Memory, there is no slow disk to watch out for, so is storage memory then the same as working memory (RAM)?

I don't think this is the case, as it means your tablet can start with, say, 15GB of "RAM" and then as you install applications and download videos or whatever it drops to under 1GB.

Does the Operating System just specially reserve an amount of flash memory for its "RAM"?

Thanks

Comment: RAM is faster than flash memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is storage memory then the same as working memory (RAM)?

No.

"Storage" is [flash memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory); "working" memory is typically [SDRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDRAM).  These have very different characteristics from each other (most noticeably bandwidth and latency).